# filtering out rows containing a specific string from entire dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter out all rows that contain a specific character (¬) in pandas.

**note: columns are about 1000, hence can't use column name in the code.**

Attempt

`filtered = pd.loc[:(pd == '¬').any(1).idxmax()]`

output: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
import numpy as np
filtered=df.loc[np.array([df[col].str.contains("¬") for col in df.columns if is_string_dtype(df[col])]).any(axis=0)]
```

Where `df` is the dataframe. You can restrict number of columns you want to iterate through, by tweaking inner list and `df.columns` accordingly (now it will iterate over all the columns, that are of string type).

Comment: though it seems it filters out all rows with strings

Comment: Only columns with strings, otherwise ```df[col].str...``` would throw an error. You can remove the ```if``` clause, in case if all your columns are string.